# Why Flex and max-height vh work not correct?

Tags: css, flexbox, height

I have `flex` container. And I have `right` and `left` flex-element inner my flex-container.

My problem: right and left blocks have not same height.
For instance:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.left {
  width: 200px
}

.right {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

And I don't understand why my right block doesn't height - 100%.
How can I fix it? I want have right block and left block same height.

Comment: The elements are the same height but the left one is **overflowing**. Try removing the `max-height` from the container.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks. I can't removing max-height because I have popup and him height must be 100vh - 50px all resolution

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: add `overflow: auto;` to the left

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's doesn't work for me

Comment: Well then you need to specify what behavior you actually want first of all. You can not have it both ways - either you let the element grow as much as needed, or you need to deal with the overflow that arises when the content is higher than the max-height you specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add +1 container for your element

```css
.container {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.left {
  width: 200px;
}

.right {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="left">
    "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements are the same height but at smaller vertical sizes, the left one *overflows*.

If the `max-height` is important, put it on the child divs instead.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
}

.container div {
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.left {
  width: 200px;
  background: lightgrey;
   
}

.right {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
    happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues
    or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except
    to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
  </div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```